# Issue deploying Sharing Rules via SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, scratch-org, sharing-rule

I am trying to deploy metadata into a scratch org from source control. The deployment is succeeding without any errors, but only Account sharing rules are deployed. Sharing rules for custom objects are missing from the org. Any guidance on what I am doing wrong?

All sharing rules in the org are criteria-based. I came across [this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpK9UAJ/sharing-rule-support-in-sfdx) idea, which suggests it isn't possible to deploy sharing rules, but I have also read in other threads that people are deploying sharing rules successfully into scratch orgs.

package.xml:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>    
<types>
    <members>ObjA.*</members>
    <members>ObjB.*</members>
    <members>ObjC.*</members>
    <name>SharingCriteriaRule</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>SharingRules</name>
</types>
```

SFDX command:

```
sf project deploy start --target-org dev-feature --wait 20 --manifest manifest/package.xml --ignore-conflicts
```

Comment: Can you make this work without using a package.xml? (I.e. with this metadata as part of a source format project directory)

Comment: Try to add to the package:
    <types>
        <members>ObjA</members>
        <members>ObjB</members>
        <members>ObjC</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
I usually deploy Sharing Rules for every object without any issue.

Comment: @PhilW When I don't explicitly reference a manifest, I get a bunch of dependency errors, as not all metadata seems to get deployed. This was resolved once I included a manifest.

Comment: @vila994 <types> <members>*</members> <name>CustomObject</name> </types> already exists elsewhere in the package.xml file. Are you suggesting that I should specify each object instead of using a wildcard?